# Splitting an integer into an array

Tags: arrays

I am trying to take an array of information (array of 8) and split it so that I can send it to an ArrayList.
I can run a a split if I create and make them all strings, but I am trying to reduce the coding (as there has to be a better way).

The first 4 of the array are strings, and the next 4 are int.

```
ArrayList<student> studentID = new ArrayList<student>();
String[] studentInfo = {"","","",""};
int [] studentInfo2 = {0,0,0,0};
for (int x = 0; x < students.length; x++)
{
    if (x < 4)
    {    
        studentInfo = students[x].split(",");
    }
    else
    {
        **studentInfo2 = students[x]();**
    }
    for (int counter = 0; counter < 8; counter++)
    {    
        if (counter < 4) //First 4 in the array are strings
        {
            studentID.add(new student(studentInfo[counter]));
        }
        else //Everything after the first 4 are Integers
        {
            studentID.add(new student(Integer.valueOf(studentInfo[counter])));
        }
    }             
}
```

I cannot figure out how to split the last 4 into an array, as I did the first 4.

EDIT:

```
    static String[] students = "1,John,Smith,John2233@gmail.com,20,88,79,59,
    2, Becky,Jones,JonesBecky123@hotmail.com,44,90,89,44,99"
```

This information is being piped into a class as seen below:
        public class student
        {
            private String studentNumber;
            private String firstName;
            private String lastName;
            private String emailAddress;
            private int age;
            private int []score = {0,0,0};
            private int score0;
            private int score1;
            private int score2;

```
/**
 * Constructor for objects of class studentObject
 */
public student(String theStudentNumber, String theFirstName, String theLastName, String theEmailAddress, int theAge, int theScore0, int theScore1, int theScore2)
{
    // initializing the instance variables
    studentNumber = theStudentNumber;
    firstName = theFirstName;
    lastName = theLastName;
    emailAddress = theEmailAddress;
    age = theAge;
    score[0] = theScore0;
    score[1] = theScore1;
    score[2] = theScore2;
}
```

Then it will call this method

```
    public void print(student printStudentInfo)
    {
        System.out.print(printStudentInfo.getStudentNumber()+"\t");
        System.out.print("First Name: " + printStudentInfo.getStudentNumber()+"\t");
        System.out.print("Last Name: " + printStudentInfo.getStudentNumber()+"\t");
        System.out.print("Age: " + printStudentInfo.getStudentNumber()+"\t");
        System.out.print("Scores : " + printStudentInfo.getStudentNumber()+"\t");
        System.out.println();
```

}

Thanks for the help ahead of time.

Comment: can you explain how students is made? with an example? I can't get the split over the element of the vector and then the loop... Please provide an example

Comment: Firstly the question is vague, its not clear. post what the student class consist and also post the result you are expecting.